# vector in column span of the matrix if the result lies in the column span and vice versa?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{mxn}$, and vectors  $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, where

$$Ax=b$$

Assuming that $b$ lies within the subspace spanned by the matrix $A$, $W:=\text{Col}\left\{A\right\}$, $b\in W$, does it follow that $x$ also lies in $W$, $x\in W$?

And vice versa, if $x\in W$, does it then follow that $b\in W$?

Comment: If the equation is satisfied, then always $b\in W$. This is because if $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and the columns of $A$ are $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$, then $Ax=x_1a_1+x_2a_2+...x_na_n\in W$. The $x$ doesn't need to be in $W$. For example, for $A=0$, then $b=0$ and $W=\{0\}$, but a non-zero $x$ will give $Ax=0=b$ and such $x\notin W$. If $m\neq n$ the vectors $x$ and $b$ are not even of the same nature, they are tuples of real numbers different sizes.

Comment: Ah ok so the product of a matrix multiplication $Ax$ lies always within $\text{Col}{\left\{A\right\}}$!

Comment: Yes, $\operatorname{Col}(A)=\{Ax:\ x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$